# how much disk space do i need for Android SDK

Tags: android, android-sdk-manager

I have 4 gb available for Android SDK. I open the SDK, pick version 5.0 api and version 4.2.2. It fills up the entire 4gb and throws warnings insufficient space.

So if I want multiple api versions, do I need 20gb, 40gb?

Comment: The packages from http://developer.android.com/tools/help/sdk-manager.html ? You can easily get over 4G, make sure not to download all those unnessecary system images. The "normal" x86 atom image is the only one you should need. And just to develop, you actually don't need them. Just the "SDK Platform" file for each version which is what you need if you target them are ~100MB each.

Answer (score 0):

Right now according to du its taking up 47GB so go big